# DAppClient with Tezos SetProvider? (this.walletProvider.mapOriginateParamsToWalletParams is not a function)

Tags: taquito

```
  const wallet = await this.getWallet(this.selectedNetwork); // get wallet using DAppClient...
  const Tezos = new TezosToolkit(this.config.rpc_endpoints[this.selectedNetwork]);
  Tezos.setProvider({
    wallet,
  });
  Tezos.wallet
      .originate({
        // some other code...
```

Hi, I'm trying to use taquito and DAppClient from @airgap/beacon-sdk and keep receiving this error:

```
TypeError: this.walletProvider.mapOriginateParamsToWalletParams is not a function
```

Is there any possible workaround maybe?

Comment: What is this `getWallet` function? After initiating the new wallet (with `new BeaconWallet(...)`), you have access to the DappClient of the Beacon SDK through `wallet.client`.

Comment: @ClaudeBarde hi, it basically gets a wallet through DAppClient, asks for permissions and then returns it if successfully. I wonder if it is possible to use DAppClient with Tezos.setProvider? I see you noticed wallet.client but it's actually undefined in my case, when I use DAppClient 

Comment: Are you using the Beacon SDK directly? I don't really understand what you are trying to achieve, `Tezos.setProvider()` only accepts an instance of a wallet recognized by Taquito, like the `BeaconWallet` or the `ThanosWallet`, you cannot spin up the DappClient provided by Beacon individually and inject it as a provider.